# Label in UICollectionViewCell not updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uilabel

In my app, I'm displaying a calendar, and I am using a collection view to show the labels for the days of the week. For some reason, all of the labels still show the default "Label" when I run the app. I looked at a similar question, but it didn't help. Any suggestions? Here is the code for the UICollectionViewCell:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CalendarTitleCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    CGSize size = [self collectionView:collectionView layout:collectionView.collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",self.weektitles[indexPath.row]];
    label.text = title;
    NSLog(@"%@", label.text);
    return cell;
}
```

FYI, I have an actual label in the storyboard (in the collection view cell).

Comment: try UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell. contentView viewWithTag:1];

Answer (score 2):

Because you create a new UILabel point label.so you revise label.text not cell label.text.

Delete

```
label = [[UILabel alloc] init]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a UICollectionViewCell name it for example DayCell with property

   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblName;
2. In storyboard change the cell Class from UICollectionViewCell to  DayCell also set Identifier as "daycell" now bind the label lblName to the label in the storyboard
3. And set the cellForItemAtIndexPath method

   ```
   - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   static NSString *identifier = @"daycell";

   DayCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


     [cell.lblName setText:@"XYZ"];


   return cell;
   }
   ```

Make sure you have properly set the delegate and datasource for the collection view.

Answer (score 0):

Both lines of code return a `UILabel`:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
```

The latter recreated a label and it doesn't belong to `UICollectionViewCell` anymore

Comment: @NickLH, you seem to have removed one ` after label in last line which has  kinda negatively affected the content of this post

Comment: It seems it comes in on your edit since I only changed "line" to "lines" but I fixed it now.